# Remove Edit Delete Link from Standard Related Lists/Views

Tags: sharing, permission-sets

We have a manage package, We want all the custom objects to be in read only mode for all the user including System Admin, i.e Neither user should be able to edit/delete the records nor view button/link to edit/delete the records.
While we are creating records using Connected App.
We do not want to use VF pages as we are to use this app on Mobile Devices also...
Please suggest.

Comment: We have also tried to modify "API Access Privileges", by modifying  [Enable Restrictions]. But it show message -"Components in this package will have the user's full API access to the following custom objects included in the package" for all the custom object used.

Comment: I want to know whether the problem has been solved. I meet the same question at the moment, if you know the answers, can you tell me the details about how you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove Edit and Delete privileges on that related object from the profile. They will disappear from the related list. Instead of that there is no way to remove them since they are links not button (but their action is same as buttons). As far as I remember you cannot simply remove/hide those.

--------------------- OR -----------------
You need to specify in your Customization Guide to do so (remove privileges)

--------------------- OR -----------------
You can create one VF page with PageblockTable which will looks like your related list except Edit/Delete links, and you can add this VF page as one of the Section in Parent (your obj) Page Layout in the end. (which also you have to mention in your Customization guide).

These are the only ways you can do this things !!! Do cudo's if found any usefull.

Comment: Hi Nilesh, Thanks for your response, But problem is that We can not have access to target org most of the time as some org are going to install our manage package.
Neither we can modify edit/delete permission for admin, while we don't want anyone to modify the records. i.e even admin.

Comment: @VikasTyagi Edited Answer with more options.

Comment: But if we go for VF page in place of related list then when there will be number of items then an scroll bar will appear as height has to be provided in px or some extra space will be there all the time.
And same have to be done for List view as well as Detail page view. 
While we are avoiding to use VF pages.
And what about #System Administrator Permissions.

Comment: Do "Pagination" for your VF page i.e. your VF page will be having a links like Related List to show/hide records accordingly. Its long go procedure. Instead of that mention in your Customization guide do Change their permission settings is the best way for you. And talking about #System Administrator - He always got all.